# Files loses extention after compression in Nifi and decompression

Tags: csv, gzip, apache-nifi

I am compresssing file named somefile.csv in nifi using CompressContent processor and when I save it on local drive and unpack it with double click in mac it is uncompressing but loses .csv extention. What's more interesting unpacking it with `gunzip` command in terminal saves the extention but the file seems corrupted. 
Filename attribute is just filename.csv before CompressContent and filename.csv.gz after so on this level it seems to work just fine. 
Using compression type bzip2 works just fine. The problem occurs only with gzip.

[CompresContet config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQacu.png)
Anyone can relate?

Comment: edit your question and provide the parameters of the CompressContent processor and the `filename` attribute value before and after processorexecuted. Also what filename you use to store fine on local drive?

Answer (score 2):

CompressContent on Nifi has several options regarding compression type, including whether to change the extension of the file.  I recommend using the flags that are included in this link:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.CompressContent/index.html

Comment: Setting Attribute "Update Filename" to True ends with files that have their extention unchanged that are in fact gzipped wich is not really something that we would like to achieve.

Comment: The default compression type is `mime.type attribute` and I think you should set to the preferred format to be compressed, such as `gzip`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use MergeContent first to create tar file, and after that you can use CompressContent (gzip format) to create .tar.gz file. An you will not loose your extensions.